# sed - Print line only if pattern is missing

Tags: sed

I have a command that outputs numerous lines that need to be parsed.

The output looks like this:

```
  PORT-A 3 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1 14 29
  PORT-B 7 HOSTNAME PRODUCT2 22 18 41
  PORT-C 9 HOSTNAME PRODUCT2 22 18 41
  PORT-D 4 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1 14
  PORT-B 2 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1
```

I've been using `sed -nr '/PRODUCT1|14|29/p'` to print only the lines that match each of those patterns.

Output using `sed -nr '/PRODUCT1|14|29/p'`:

```
  PORT-A 3 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1 14 29
  PORT-D 4 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1 14
  PORT-B 2 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1
```

I would like `sed` to print the lines only if one of those 3 patterns is missing. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Ideal Output:

```
  PORT-D 4 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1 14
  PORT-B 2 HOSTNAME PRODUCT1
```

Comment: In your example, the second and the third line don't match any pattern. What are you really looking?

Comment: If you have GNU sed, you could attempt to replace the 3rd instance, and branch past the print if you succeed: `sed -nr '/PRODUCT1|14|29/ {s//&/3; t; p}'`. In perl, you could actually count the matches.

Comment: your question's title is different from your body -- you want lines printed .... when, exactly? "all patterns don't match"? "only if one of those 3 patterns is missing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to be able to do this easily with `sed`. If I understand your needs correctly, you want to print the line if exactly one of three patterns do not match, and exactly two patterns *do* match. In sed, this would require three execution paths. In each, you would need to test for a successful match for each of two patterns, and test for an unsuccessful match for the third.

For the sake of completeness, the following `sed` script achieves your stated needs:

```
sed -nr '/PRODUCT1/{/14/{/29/!p}};/14/{/29/{/PRODUCT1/!p}};/PRODUCT1/{/29/{/14/!p}}'
```

Note that this performs regex matches with O(n^2) complexity. If you add more patterns to test more fields, this becomes ... unwieldy.

You will probably be better off doing something like this in `awk` or `perl`, where you can implement counter variables. In such languages, test for each pattern, increment one counter if matched and the other counter for each pattern tested. If the match counter is one less than the pattern counter, print the line.

Comment: Thank you, wyrm! This helps immensely. You're right, from the looks of the sed script I would probably be better off doing this with awk or perl.